# ValueError at /account/register/

Tags: python, django, valueerror

Can anyone help me figure this out? I keep getting a valueError saying my view isn't returning an HttpResponse! I'm not sure what could be causing the error. I checked my indentations, as well as all of my urls. I'm using the redirect(reverse()) function to call the url in my views.

here's the traceback:
Internal Server Error: /account/register/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 198, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view accounts.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Here are my accounts/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

from accounts.forms import (
    RegistrationForm,
    EditProfileForm
)

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('home:home'))
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
            args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)

def view_profile(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        user = request.user
        args = {'user': user}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)

def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', args)

def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:view_profile'))
        else:
            return redirect(reverse('accounts:change_password'))
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', args)
```

and here are my accounts/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    login, logout, password_reset, password_reset_done, password_reset_confirm,
    password_reset_complete
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'accounts/login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name': 'accounts/logout.html'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile_with_pk'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),

    url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password.html', 'post_reset_redirect': 'accounts:password_reset_done', 'email_template_name': 'accounts/reset_password_email.html'}, name='reset_password'),

    url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),

    url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', password_reset_confirm, {'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password_confirm.html', 'post_reset_redirect': 'accounts:password_reset_complete'}, name='password_reset_confirm'),

    url(r'^reset-password/complete/$', password_reset_complete,{'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password_complete.html'}, name='password_reset_complete')

]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your function...

```
def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('home:home'))
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
            args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

`render` is inside of the if statement so if the method isn't post the function is returning none as the error message would suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Should i moved render somewhere else? I get an error no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your views,

```
def register(request): 
    if request.method =='POST': 
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() 
            return redirect(reverse('home:home')) 
    else: 
        form = RegistrationForm()
    args = {'form': form} 
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

The render function should be outside the if statement. Also, the args should be outside the if statement too. That's why the ValueError is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('home:home'))
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

Notice, I have changed the indentation of else and return statements.